# Searching text using LIKE, and Included Column

Tags: index, sql-server-2017, index-tuning, nonclustered-index

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (Column1 = 'ED69K')    

SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (Column1 LIKE '% ED69K%')
```

I have a wide table with 25 columns on the table. The above queries do need to do key lookup and also nested joins as the index is only created on column1 .

The database is an oltp database with constant read/writes.

Due to the nested joins / key lookups with millions of rows the database often blocks the inserts.

My question is if I create a non-clustered index with included columns on column 1 and  the rest of the 24 columns which will remove nested joins and key lookups are there any downsides regarding performance.

In order to remove table scan due to like clause with leading wildcard now can I create a full text index on the same column 1.

I will greatly appreciate as due to the nature of the queries it is creating constant locks and as a result the application is getting slow day by day.

Comment: I've removed the mention of Full-Text Search from the title, as well as the corresponding tag. [Full-Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search) is a very specific component of SQL Server that involves predicates like `CONTAINS` or `FREETEXT`; using `LIKE` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: It will speed up these queries but slow down inserts and updates. The second query might not be sped up very much due to the wildcard search. Is that acceptable to you? You should probably avoid `select *` and specify only the columns you really need. A full-text index is not relevant for `LIKE` and will just slow down update for no benefit